# Dynamic disabling reactive forms of FormControl in Angular

Tags: typescript

I am trying to disable one of radiobuttons in my FormControl  group of radiobuttons, but it is not possible. Changing status to disable: true in ts file is disabling the group of radiobuttons, not only single one. My html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <radiobutton-group>
     Food:
    <radiobutton [FormControl]="myForm.get('food')" value="apple"></radiobutton>
    <radiobutton [FormControl]="myForm.get('food')" value="pear"></radiobutton>
    <radiobutton [FormControl]="myForm.get('food')" value="orange"></radiobutton>
  </radiobutton-group>
</form>
```

And my typescript code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  templateUrl: './radio-button-food.component.html'
})
export class RadioButtonFoodComponent {
  myForm: any = new FormGroup({
    food: new FormControl({ value: 'apple', disabled: false}),
    drink: new FormControl('coke'),
  });
 }
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? To disable only one radiobutton? Putting `disable = true` inside `<radiobutton>` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to [attr.disabled] instead of [disabled] in the template worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set or patch the value of the control. 
docs are at https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

example code:

`myForm.controls['food'].patchValue({ value: 'apple', disabled: false});`

in general, ng suggests that you do not mix reactive forms with disabled attribute html binding.